# How to get Ruby OpenID to use sreg 1.1 and not 1.0

Tags: ruby, openid

I need the namespace for the OpenID sreg to be http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1 and not http://openid.net/sreg/1.0. How can I set OpenID to use 1.1? Can I set something in an intializer? OR is there something else Im not setting making openid think it can't use sreg 1.1?

More specifically I need

openid.ns.ext0=http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1

and not

openid.ns.ext0=http://openid.net/sreg/1.0

```
def open_id
    begin
      oidreq = openid_consumer.begin 'https://openid.intuit.com/openid/xrds'
    rescue OpenID::DiscoveryFailure => why
        "Sorry, we couldn't find your identifier '#{openid}'"
    else
        oidreq.add_extension_arg('sreg','required','email')
        oidreq.add_extension_arg('sreg','optional','fullname')

        redirect_to oidreq.redirect_url(root_url, root_url + "open_id_complete")    
    end
  end

  def self.openid_store
    @openid_store ||= OpenID::Store::Memory.new
  end

  def openid_consumer
    @openid_consumer ||= OpenID::Consumer.new(session, self.class.openid_store)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer! I had to create a new sreg request and then that used 1.1

```
       sregreq = OpenID::SReg::Request.new
       # required fields
       sregreq.request_fields(['email'], true)
       # optional fields
       sregreq.request_fields(['fullname'], false)
       oidreq.add_extension(sregreq)
```